# AngularJS http post and delete data

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Using angularjs and c# webapi here.

I am making a call to my webapi from angularjs passing in my json array.

Angularjs code:

```
    factory.delete  = function (json) {
    var url = 'myUrl';
    return $http.post(url, json).then(function (res) {
        return res;
    }, function (err) {            
        throw err;
    });
   }
```

C# Api:

```
  [HttpPost("data/delete")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteData([FromBody] List<UserEntity> 
  jsonData)
  {
     //loop through json and do delete here
  }
```

Is the correct way to delete, I am using post and not httpdelete here.The above method works

I tried to use http delete as:

```
 factory.delete  = function (ids) {
    var url = 'myUrl';
    return $http.delete(url, ids).then(function (res) {
        return res;
    }, function (err) {            
        throw err;
    });
   }

   [HttpDelete("data/{ids}/delete")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteData(string ids)
    {

       //here ids is comma separated ids which I want to loop through and delete one by one

    }
```

The issue with this is that my ids parameter in api is always null. Not sure whats going on here.

Any inputs please.

Comment: Please supply an example json payload as well as the content of the UserEntity class. Since these two are dependent, a miss-match here will result in a null for your parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but will help you debug your issue. Adding the following code in your API class will give more insight to the json conversion to your parameters:

```cs
[HttpPost("data/delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteData([FromBody] List<UserEntity> jsonData)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var error = ModelState.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Exception != null);

        return BadRequest(error != null 
            ? error.Exception.Message
            : "Error in JSON request");
     }
     // your regular processing code
}
```

Comment: @carlos my api is in my separate .net core project , I dont get ModelState there. Also as I mentioned in my post for HttpPost its working fine. I can get my json very well back in my api controller.  I can then loop through that json, and delete the data. My question was is this the correct way to delete, I mean using http post and not using http delete. Now coming to HttpDelete when I thought using HttpDelete instead of HttpPost and sending just the Id's the parameter id is always null.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the miss understanding. I actually would use the [HttpDelete] option. How are you calling this? Are you selecting the "DELETE" method in your REST client then using a URL like so http://.../api/data/123/delete

Comment: I have posted the code for the delete in my post. I am using angularjs to make calls to my api

Comment: It seems to me that the $http.delete should be called like so instead: $http.delete('https://<yourhost>/api/data/' + ids + '/delete');

Comment: Carlo I am already doing that. Looks like there is some other issue.